# Sigma bond by combining two p orbitals

Tags: bond, molecular-orbital-theory

> If I combine two p orbitals in such a way that they form σ bonds, which linear combination will represent bonding and antibonding?

My work on this problem:

$$
\begin{align}
&\text{Bonding:} &(\phi_1 - \phi_2)\\
&\text{Antibonding:} &(\phi_1 + \phi_2)
\end{align}
$$

where $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are the wavefunctions of 1st and 2nd p orbitals.

Reason: While forming a bond, in bonding combination two lobes of same phase will overlap so they are actually mirror images of each other, and therefore they are negative of each other.
While in antibonding combination opposite phase combine, so the wavefunctions are actually added. 
Is this correct?

Comment: There is no point in tracking individual orbital signs, for they are all arbitrary anyway. Other than that, you are right.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! U are saying that what I have written ( Y1-Y2) for bonding and (Y1+Y2) for antibonding is correct?

Comment: Provided that both orbital signs are chosen in the same way with respect to the axis directed along the bond, **yes**.

Comment: I want to share a picture with you how can I do that

Comment: There is no need for a picture, I think you got it right. Then again, you may edit your question and attach the image to it.

Comment: My teacher gave me wrong :(

Comment: Then they must have had a _different_ picture in mind, and I would be glad to see both, but that's impossible unless you can read minds.

Comment: No our diagrams were same....ok imagine this axis of overlapping is z axis and 2 Pz orbitals are overlapping one coming from -infinity other coming from +infinity...now tell

Comment: That's the picture I had in mind from the very beginning.